# Nested quotes in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, quotes

Please let me explain my scenario with some sample script which is much simpler than my actual application but shows the same behavior:

For the demo I use two bash shell scripts. The first one is called `argtest.sh` simply outputs the command line parameters:

```
#/bin/bash

echo "Argument 1: $1"
echo "Argument 2: $2"
```

Test:

```
root@test:~# ./argtest.sh 1 2
Argument 1: 1
Argument 2: 2
```

and

```
root@test:~# ./argtest.sh "1 2" 3
Argument 1: 1 2
Argument 2: 3
```

This works as expected

I've created another command like this:

```
./argtest.sh $(for i in ` seq 1 2 ` ; do echo Number $i; done)
```

This is the result

```
Argument 1: Number
Argument 2: 1
```

I've tried many different combinations of quotation marks (") and escaped quotation marks (\") around `Number`, but no combination produced the desired output of:

```
Argument 1: Number 1
Argument 2: Number 2
```

How can I get to that output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because arguments are subject to word splitting, you may change `$IFS` and put the the new separator into your `echo`

```
IFS=$'_\n'
./argtest.sh $(for i in {1..2} ; do echo "Number ${i}_"; done )
```

don't forget to restore the old $IFS

```
oIFS=$IFS
...
IFS=$oIFS
```

btw `{1..2}` is equivalent to `seq 1 2` but you don't need an external command

Comment: Basically, all answers are similar and all seem correct to me (now, that I understand), but I marked this as the correct answer, as I solved my issue using this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The command substitution is subject to word-splitting. Its output is two lines

```
Number 1
Number 2
```

but newlines are treated as arbitrary whitespace during word splitting. As a result, the command substitution is split into 4 words (`Number`, `1`, `Number`, and `2`), each of which is a separate argument to `argtest.sh`.

Additional quotes would treated literally during word-splitting; a string like `"a b" c` is split into 3 words (`"a`, `b"`, and `c`), not 2 (`a b`, `c`).

To do what you want, you need to use a `while` loop to read one line of output at a time from your loop. For example:

```
for i in $(seq 1 2); do
  echo "Number $i"
done | while read -r line; do
  ./argtest.sh "$line"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

As chepner mentioned, command substitution is subjected to word splitting.

Below are few examples to better understand this

Here is the behaviour when I replace `echo` with `printf` and escape the double quotes:-

```
for i in ` seq 1 2 ` ; do printf "\"Number %d\" " "$i"; done; printf "\n"
"Number 1" "Number 2"

./arg.sh  $(for i in ` seq 1 2 ` ; do printf "\"Number %d\" " "$i"; done; printf "\n")
Argument 1: "Number                                                                   
Argument 2: 1"
```

Now if I try to enclose the whole command substitution in double quotes, it will consider them as one single argument:-

```
./arg.sh "$(for i in ` seq 1 2 ` ; do printf "\"Number %d\" " "$i"; done; printf "\n")"
Argument 1: "Number 1" "Number 2"                                                                                                                         
Argument 2:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs`

```
for i in ` seq 1 2 ` ; do echo Number $i; done | xargs -d $'\n' ./argtest.sh
```